# Feedback please?

Tags: sound-design, video-games, demo

Hi Everybody

Redesigned the sound for tthis gameplay capture video.
Your feedback is much apreciated!

[vimeo]20855046[/vimeo]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I seems sounds mostly ok, did you record them by yourself or you use some library? 
The main thing that it should be different sound inside and outside your mech, just try play with reverb and frequencies. Inside short metal, outside open space big delay, something like this. When you're inside cabin you hear outside sounds with different frequency range less mid-high and high sounds. Outside metal meets rockets and bullets, ricochets. It will be good hear pilot reaction too:)) sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote out a long critique, then realized that the headphones I'm listening on are far from adequate and I was hearing far more sweeteners than anything with bass.

After turning it up, the environment felt better, but I was still lacking the weighty impacts that would result from mechs multiple stories tall.  Also, IMO, the HUD sounds inside the cockpit are a bit too loud.

I'll give a much better critique when I can watch this on my home machine with decent monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much thought the same as Dave.

The steps and movements (for example the rocket hatch at 0:31s) are to weak. 
Not to quiet but to small.
The same for the collapsed building.

You don't realize the monstrous size of this things. (Which you surely intend)

I like the HUD sounds. But they are to loud.

I don't like the machine gun sound.
And it feels strange that its louder inside than outside the cockpit.

It needs more ambience. (Especially outside) Or will there be music?

In comparison I watched the original after i watched yours.
I like your sound design more than that.
But without the voices and the music you don't get the emotional impact.
And with the music of the original trailer it's to much sound design, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sounds are great but it is a little bit too much.  Theres too many of them or they are too loud.  I don't know if you are trying to go for a Battlefield 3 type thing with no music at all or not but something like that or a bit of atmosphhere instead of of the many sounds because they are most likely mixed a little high and get annoying with the reptetivity.